# STM32, mass storage device. how to properly erase memory sectors?

Tags: usb, stm32, c

I want to organize a USB stick based on STM32F105RBT + AT45DB041.
Problem: after reconnecting the device to a PC, windows7 asks to format the disk.

Problem identification algorithm:

1. Connect to PC
2. Format the USB flash drive (formatting is completed successfully)
3. Write any file to a USB flash drive
4. Disconnect the USB flash drive from the PC
5. Connect device to PC
   Result: Windows asks to format the USB flash drive

Everything works fine if:
Size of file (-files) <= 12KB
(After reconnecting the USB flash drive to the PC, the file opens successfully, the data is not damaged)

SPI memory AT45DB041 has a total of 2048 pages of 264 bytes each. Writing / reading is performed at 256 bytes per page. Writing a 512 byte block requires two pages of memory.

I am sure that the problem is in the procedure for erasing memory sectors, in the STORAGE_Write_FS function, but I don’t understand where I went wrong?

```
    int8_t STORAGE_Write_FS(uint8_t lun, uint8_t *buf, uint32_t blk_addr, uint16_t blk_len)
    {
      /* USER CODE BEGIN 7 */
      AT45dbxx_ErasePage(blk_addr*2);
      AT45dbxx_ErasePage(blk_addr*2+1);
      AT45dbxx_WritePage(buf, 256, (uint16_t)blk_addr*2);
      AT45dbxx_WritePage(buf+256, 256, (uint16_t)blk_addr*2+1);
      return (USBD_OK);
    
      /* USER CODE END 7 */
    }

void AT45dbxx_ErasePage(uint16_t page)
{
    page = page << AT45dbxx.Shift; // AT45dbxx.Shift = 9 For 264 byte per page 
    AT45dbxx_Resume();
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(AT45DB_PGERASE); // CMD 0x81
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 16) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 8) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(page & 0xff);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();
}

void AT45dbxx_WritePage(uint8_t *Data,uint16_t len,uint16_t page)
{
    page = page << AT45dbxx.Shift;  // AT45dbxx.Shift = 9 For 264 byte per page 
    AT45dbxx_Resume();
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(AT45DB_MNTHRUBF1);  // CMD 0x82
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 16) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 8) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(page & 0xff);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&_45DBXX_SPI,Data,len,100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();    
}
```

Functions for working with memory work correctly in the entire range of pages. The flash drive is formatted using windows before recording.

Comment: If you look at the disk image, you might be able to see what type of corruption is happening. (I recommend using HxD, a hex editor which can directly show you the bytes on a disk)

Comment: How have you established that your memory functions all work correctly over the entire range? Can you describe your testing method? With the wrong kind of tests it can be difficult to spot issues where your addressing is incorrect and possibly overwriting data unintentionally.

Comment: I"m looking through the datasheet for your AT45DB041 device, and I don't see a stand-alone "Page Erase" command - the only erases I see are built in to the page-program commands. What are you using for `AT45DB_PGERASE`?

Comment: @user253751,Thanks for the recommendation to use HxD

Comment: @brhans The memory testing algorithm is as follows:
0. Clear all memory
1. Fill 264 bytes buffer_1 with random values (data generation)
2. Write the generated data to page 0
3. Read page 0 to buffer_2
4.compare buffer_1 and buffer_2
5. If there is a comparison error - report the error
6. Repeat steps 1-5 for all memory pages

Comment: @brhans I used the command 0x81 The Page Erase command can be used to individually erase any page in the main memory array allowing the Buffer to Main Memory Page Program to be utilized at a later time. To perform a page erase in the DataFlash standard page size (264-bytes), an opcode of 81H must be loaded
into the device, followed by three address bytes comprised of four don’t care bits, 11 page address bits (PA10 - PA0) that specify the page in the main memory to be erased and nine don’t care bits.

Comment: You already asked this **do not repost**  at least one of your copies is at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64336450/stm32-mass-storage-device-how-to-properly-erase-memory-sectors  but you posted here too.  **Deleting then reposting is prohibited**

Comment: I found that the download area gets overwritten. Why is this happening I cannot understand

Comment: So it seems to me that your testing will not catch an issue where something goes wrong with addressing. What happens if there's a situation where the memory device always sees one of the address bit values stuck low (maybe there's a problem with the way you're sending the address to the device). You think you're writing & reading pages 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 - but say bit 2 is stuck low - then you'll actually be writing pages 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3 - your test won't catch that. But this kind of thing is exactly what could cause the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: I'm not finding a command 81H in [this datasheet](http://www.orangetags.com/wp-content/downloads/datasheet/Atmel/45DB041.pdf). Do you have a more detailed one?

Comment: Your `page` parameter is a `uint_16`, but you're shifting it left 9 bits. You're effectively reducing your page address down to 7 bits. 128 pages x 256 bytes == 32k. Assuming your filesystem takes 20k of overhead (FAT tables) then once you write more than 12k to a file you'll wrap around and start overwriting the filesystem stuff and windows then will want to reformat it...

Comment: @brhans I am using AT45DB041E-SSHN Adesto (Not Atmel) I am sorry for the inaccuracy in the description. Thanks for the answer about the mem test. I will test again, using different algorithms

Comment: @brhans  Yes you are right. I fixed uint16_t to uint32_t and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed uint16_t page to uint32_t page  and it worked. Thanks!

```
void AT45dbxx_ErasePage(uint32_t page)
{
    page = page << AT45dbxx.Shift; // AT45dbxx.Shift = 9 For 264 byte per page 
    AT45dbxx_Resume();
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(AT45DB_PGERASE); // CMD 0x81
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 16) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 8) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(page & 0xff);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();
}
void AT45dbxx_WritePage(uint8_t *Data,uint16_t len,uint32_t page)
{
    page = page << AT45dbxx.Shift;  // AT45dbxx.Shift = 9 For 264 byte per page 
    AT45dbxx_Resume();
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(AT45DB_MNTHRUBF1);  // CMD 0x82
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 16) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi((page >> 8) & 0xff);
    AT45dbxx_Spi(page & 0xff);
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&_45DBXX_SPI,Data,len,100);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(_45DBXX_CS_GPIO,_45DBXX_CS_PIN,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    AT45dbxx_WaitBusy();    
}
```